# nHibernate + wcf + Isession

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

I have a c# solution with 3 projects - Data, WCF and UI. The first one is a class library that talks to db. It's exposed via the second one, which is of type WCF Service Library - the reason for that is it will be exposed in third project - Asp.net app called UI - as a simple svc pointing to dll.

Just to point it out, I'm not using Repository pattern.

I need to have ISession for a WCF call (similiar to Session-per-request approach for asp.net). Can anyone share a solution that simply works? I don't want to use any IOC for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WcfOperationSessionContext` (new in 3.0).

Once bound, your Data classes just have to use `SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()`.

Comment: Will use it for sure. Just when nh will not be alpha anymore!

Comment: If that's an issue, you can just copy the class from here: https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Context/WcfOperationSessionContext.cs and use it in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to service is associated with unique OperationContext. OperationContext doesn't have any store for custom objects but you can implement [extension](http://hyperthink.net/blog/a-simple-ish-approach-to-custom-context-in-wcf/). By setting session in MessageInspector you can initiate NHibernate Session per call in centralized place and access your extended context in any operation.

Comment: This is quite WCF-related. What about using this ISession in Data project? I would like to keep it without any WCF context related knowledge.