# What is the best practice using NHibernate 3.0 with WCF Web Services?

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

There seems to be quite a bit of information regarding using NHibernate and WCF Web Services but I'm struggling to find a definitive guide on how to implement the two technologies together in a efficient, thread safe way.

Specifically I want to grab the ISession object and uses that to get and save data through my existing repositories. My Business Objects, Unit Tests and ASP.NET Web Application all use the NHibernate framework and it works just great (it's my first hobby project using an ORM). My big question is how to combine this great framework with WCF Web Services.

I've read that version 3.0 NHibernate has NHibernate.Context.WcfOperationSessionContext but I'm unsure of it's implementation ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665068/nhibernate-wcf-isession)). From what I understand, one option is to store the ISession object in the OperationContext?

Can anyone point me in the direction of a implementation example?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [post](http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2011/03/nhibernate-session-per-request-with-wcfoperationsessioncontext.html) describing, in detail, all the steps for registering and using the WcfOperationSessionContext. It also includes instructions for using it with the agatha-rrsl project.

Comment: A follow up post is [here](http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2011/04/nhibernate-session-per-request-with-wcfoperationsessioncontext-part2.html)

Comment: I'm following your work here Nikos. This is fantastic stuff! Very nice WCF hooks here.

Comment: @JoshRobinson Thank you :) You may also download the sample from https://github.com/moodmosaic/BonusBits.CodeSamples/tree/master/BonusBits.CodeSamples.NHibernate/WcfOperationSessionContext

Comment: I had that solution open on my client machine this morn! I have that working now. I've added comments to give you attribution - even on stuff I've altered.

Comment: How would like the implementation if several session factories are needed in a distributed transaction environment?

Comment: You have to handle this manually, since the `ISession` is not really thread-safe and `ISessionFactory`’s `GetCurrentSession` *can* throw in two-phase commit protocols.

Answer (score 1):

WCF and Nhibernate work together in [Sharp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) project. You can have a look at their implementation

Comment: Have you used this Sharp Architecture framework? If so, what were your thoughts on it? I looked briefly at the wiki last night before posting my question, there was no documentation regarding WCF Support.

Comment: Its one of the best architecture frameworks that I've ever seen. You can have a look a WCF usage in the Northwind sample https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Northwind/tree/master/app/Northwind.Wcf